# How to properly use async await on a database query

Tags: javascript, express

This is the very basic route I am using:

```js
router.get('/:date', async (req, res) => {
    let tracks = []
    let query = 'SELECT * from `tracks` where `playlistDate` = \''+req.params.date+'\''
    let result = await pool.query(query)
    console.log(result)
})
```

I know this by itself won't work, but what do I need to do to be able to use await on the query function like this?

---

This is the pool, with the credentials and addr changed.

```
var pool  = mysql.createPool({
    poolLimit : 10,
    host            : 'HOST',
    user            : 'USER',
    password        : 'PASS',
    database        : 'DB'
});
```

Comment: does `pool.query` method return a Promise? if so, your code is correct

Comment: @JaromandaX I'm not really sure about that. This is a built-in function, not something I wrote.

Comment: @Laif Where is `pool` defined? Please post more context.

Comment: are you using npm mysql for node?

Comment: you should check the docs to the lib your using, mysql one for sure has many many examples, and is very common lib to use so your find 100's of tutorials.. your code is open to SQL injection it should use `playlistDate = ?` and pass it in as a param. see the docs it would have examples.

Comment: it really depends on the library you use ... mysql2 you'd use `await pool.query(query).promise()` for example

Comment: Exactly what you just did. Keep in mind that you'll have to use something like Express Async Handler to catch errors during the database query. https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-async-handler

Comment: @Dai I didn't include it because of how basic it is, but I included it in the question

Comment: @elpmid Yes, I am.

Comment: I've heard https://www.npmjs.com/package/autorm makes it simple (shameless plug)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this logic would help. It depends on how you structured it.

```js
var pool  = mysql.createPool({
    poolLimit : 10,
    host            : 'HOST',
    user            : 'USER',
    password        : 'PASS',
    database        : 'DB'
});


const getTracks = (date) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let query = 'SELECT * FROM tracks WHERE playlistDate = ?'
    
    pool.query(query, [date], (err, res) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
        return;
      }
      
      resolve(res);
    })
  })
};


router.get('/:date', async (req, res) => {
    try {
      let tracks = await getTracks(req.params.date);
      return res.status(200).json(tracks);
    } catch (err) {
      return res.status(400).json(err);
    }
    
})
```